# 404 Not Found - node-gyp

Tags: node.js, restify, node-gyp

This morning I've been diving into the wonderful (and quite frustrating) world of NodeJS. I'm now wanting to install node-restify and, after a bit of research, now realise I need to install a package called node-gyp (https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) to make this happen.

However, `npm install -g node-gyp` comes back in my NodeJS with a **404 Not Found - node-gyp is not in the npm system registry** error, brilliant!

Can anyone advise as to why this is, other than the obvious? And potentially any workarounds?

Comment: which node version you working on?

Comment: v0.10.30, 
npm installer 1.4.21

Comment: Windows, think that's half the problem here =/

Comment: do you have python 2.7.x installed?

Comment: Yep, 2.7.8 under the C:\Python27 folder.

Comment: One of the errors comes out: 25 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nope-gyp (404)

Comment: can you paste the complete error log

Answer (score 0):

You need to install node-gyp with the command

```
 npm install -g node-gyp
```

instead of

```
npm-install -g node-gyp
```

and then restify by

```
npm install restify
```

Comment: Sorry, typo in my main post, I'm using npm install, not npm-install. Still coming up with 404.